# How do I make adaptive text using the Typography component from Ant design 5?

Tags: css, user-interface, text, antd

Using Ant design 5.3.0

The Typography component has 3 elements: Title, Text Paragraph. How can I make the text they render shrink/enlarge according to the current screen resolution?

Now text rendered by Typography is not responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of ways to do it is installing "react-responsive" - the library which is specified among third-party libraries at official ant design website